# Django, Ajax and Fotorama DB update

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to get images added to Fotorama Image slider from Django DB  so far with no luck i would tremendously appreciate any assistance.
I'm able to see the AJAX function returns values on the inspector console how ever cant get slider to display them.

this is my urls.py

```
url(r'image/busqueda/$', views.ImageBusqueda.as_view(), name='image-busqueda'),
```

this is my  views.py

```
class ImageBusqueda(generic.TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        images =  Images.objects.all()
        data = serializers.serialize('json' ,images, fields=
               ('imagen','nombre','duracion'))
        return HttpResponse(data)
```

and this is my JS

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.fotorama')


            .on('fotorama:show', function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url:'/image/busqueda/',
                    type:'get',
                    datatype:'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        var img = ""
                        for(var i = 0; i<data.lenght; i ++ ){
                            img += '<img src="' + data[i].fields.imagen + '"data-id="' + data[i].id + '">'

                        }
                        $('#img').html(img);
                    }

                });

            })
</script>
```

this is the HTML

```
    <div class="fotorama"
         data-nav="false"
         data-shuffle="true"
         data-autoplay="true"
         data-arrows="false"
         data-loop="true"
         data-transition="dissolve"
         data-fit="cover"
         data-width="100%"
         data-height="100%"
    >
{# NORMAL DJANGO WAY #}
        {#        {% for img in imagenes %}#}
        {#            <img src="{{ img.imagen.url }}" data-id="{{ img.id }}" >#}
        {#        {% endfor %} #}


       {# JS WAY #}
        <div id="img">

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors for those images?

Comment: no  just a white screen  the dev console shows

Comment: 'code' [19/Sep/2017 20:44:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3847
'code' [19/Sep/2017 20:44:07] "GET /static/signage/css/fotorama.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1786
'code' [19/Sep/2017 20:44:07] "GET /static/signage/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1813
'code' [19/Sep/2017 20:44:13] "GET /image/busqueda/ HTTP/1.1" 200 245

Comment: Can you open the `Network` panel in the dev console and then make the AJAX request? Do you see the images being loaded there?

Comment: i can't see the actual images  all i get is  this:
'[{"model": "signage.images", "pk": 36, "fields": {"imagen": "1swGj9_7oxrYGA.jpg", "nombre": "uno", "duracion": "10000"}}, {"model": "signage.images", "pk": 38, "fields": {"imagen": "layout_rDZOPvV.png", "nombre": "layout", "duracion": "20000"}}]'

Comment: The problem here is that the values for `imagen` are just names of the images. Whereas to load the images in the browser you need the full path (i.e. the `imagen.url`). Django's built-in serializer doesn't serialize methods so you can't make it return `imagen.url`. You'll have to write a custom serializer to be able to get a full image url. It shouldn't be difficult, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build upon my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309554/django-ajax-and-fotorama-db-update/46310275#comment79581955_46309554), here's a minimal for loop to serialize your model:

```
import json

class ImageBusqueda(generic.TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        images =  Images.objects.all()

        data_list = []
        for image in queryset:
            data_list.append({
                'imagen': image.imagen.url,
                'nombre': image.nombre,
                'duracion': image.duracion
            })

       data = json.dumps(data_list)
       return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

---

**NOTE:** This approach of manually serializing objects is pretty good if you have to use it in one view. If you want to use it in multiple views, I'd recommond that you move this into a separate function solely dedicated to serializing. That way you can access it in other views as well instead of just copying the code again and again.